# What is wrong with Lightbox Gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

For some reason when I code this it comes up as 2 images and they aren't clickable. I'm trying to create a lightbox image gallery but my code is off somehow. There is a bunch of random stuff in the css for other content of my website but if you see an error there please let me know.

```css
.stripe {
    background-color: #79EBC6;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    margin: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #58E4B3;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.navbar a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #58E4B3;
}
.nav li {
    float:left;
}
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    padding: 1rem;
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    flex: 0 1 32%;
}
.cards {
    margin-top: 5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15rem;
}
.collapse {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.jumbotron {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #79EBC6;
}
.carousel {
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2em;
}
.tab-pane {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
}
.display-4 {
    text-align: center;
}
.fa-check {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
.d-flex {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.section {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

.form-row {
    text-align: left;
}
.modal-body {
    text-align: left;
}
.btn-button1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #58E4B3;
}
.card-body {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
}
.card-body .btn-success {
    margin-left: .5em;
}

body {
    font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
    margin:10px;
    font-size:16px;
}

#demo {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.green{
    background-color:#6fb936;
}
.thumb{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.page-top{
    margin-top:85px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap 4.2</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Your Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h2 class="mb-5 text-center">Photo Gallery</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row text-center text-lg-left align-items-end">


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">


                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumb">
                <a href="images/150.png" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Caption">
                    <img  src="images/150.png" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="images/150.png" alt="">

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>




</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ekko-lightbox"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is one of the last few things needed for a big assignment in a class I'm taking so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to add your js full path and css full path... for better understanding.. if we don't see issue then how we solve this?

Comment: `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ekko-lightbox`isn't correct, you don't point to the files `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css`